# Summarising Data in R

Tags: r, pivot-table

I'm sure this is really easy, but as an R novice I'm tearing my hair out.

I have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame("Factor_1" = c(1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                 "Factor_2" = c("M", "F", "M", "F","M", "F","M", "F","M", "F","M", "F"),
                 "Denominator" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                 "Numerator" = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1))
```

I want to create some graphs:

```
(1) Sum(Denominator) - split by Factor_1
(2) Sum(Numerator)/Sum(Denominator) - split by Factor_1

(so Factor_1 appears on the horizontal axis)

(and then repeat for Factor_2)
```

Ideally with (1) and (2) having different vertical axes and with (1) as columns and (2) as lines.

Would look a bit like the attached picture (from an Excel pivot table/graph):

[Pivot Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wSRk.png)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show what you tried so far and describe exactly where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Have edited original post to show an example of a small chunk of data. I've tried various things - plot, boxplot, ggplot, etc. but I'm afraid I just don't know what to do. I can't imagine this is a difficult thing to do though.

Comment: could the rpivotTable package be my friend here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of thinking of this problem like a pivot in Excel, start thinking about this as a prime opportunity to use the `tidyverse`!

Let's set up our environment:

```
library(tidyverse)   # This will load dplyr and tidyverse to make visualization easier!

df <- data.frame("Factor_1" = c(1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2),   
             "Factor_2" = c("M", "F", "M", "F","M", "F","M", "F","M", "F","M", "F"),   
             "Denominator" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),   
             "Numerator" = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1))
```

First let's work with Factor_1. First, we want the Numerator and Denominator sums and Numerator/Denominator ratio for each Factor_1 group. We need to tell R that we want to *group by* Factor_1. Then we can use the `summarize()` function in `dplyr` package to do the majority of our heavy lifting.

```
summaryFactor1 <- df %>%                     # Save as new object: summaryFactor1
group_by(Factor_1) %>%                       # Group data by Factor_1, and for each:
summarize(sum_num = sum(Numerator),          # sum Numerator
        sum_den = sum(Denominator)) %>%      # sum Denominator
mutate(ratio = sum_num/sum_den)              # and create new column for num/den
```

This will give us:

```
summaryFactor1
#  A tibble: 2 x 4
  Factor_1 sum_num sum_den ratio
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1        1       3       7 0.429
2        2       1       5 0.2
```

And to reproduce the graph you're looking for, we take our `summaryFactor1` tibble and use ggplot:

```
summaryFactor1 %>%                        # Use our summary table
ggplot(aes(x = Factor_1)) +               # plot Factor_1 on x-axis, 
geom_col(aes(y = sum_den)) +              # sum_den as columns, 
geom_line(aes(y = ratio))                 # and ratio as a line
```

[image: Factor_1 summary plot]

Notice there is only one y-axis, and thus the line plotting the ratio is difficult to interpret. While your desired plot that you shared from Excel *looks* better, be wary of the misinterpretation of that ratio.

We can use the same logic as above to Factor_2:

```
summaryFactor2 <- df %>%                     # Save as new object: summaryFactor1                    
group_by(Factor_2) %>%                       # Group data by Factor2, and for each:    
summarize(sum_num = sum(Numerator),          # sum Numerator
        sum_den = sum(Denominator)) %>%      # sum Denominator
mutate(ratio = sum_num/sum_den)              # and create new column for num/den

# Let's view the result
summaryFactor2
# A tibble: 2 x 4
 Factor_2 sum_num sum_den ratio
  <fct>      <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 F              1       6 0.167
2 M              3       6 0.5
```

Before we move on, notice that the sum of Denominator for each group is the same. When we compared ratio's within Factor_1's groups, note that the two groups have a different Denominator sums, so this is an easier 1:1 comparison.

Since plotting `sum_den` between the two groups won't be very insightful...

```
summaryFactor2
ggplot(aes(x = Factor_2)) + 
geom_col(aes(y = sum_den))
```

[image: Factor2 summary plot]

let's instead plot the ratio:

```
summaryFactor2 %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = Factor_2)) + 
geom_col(aes(y = ratio))
```

[image: Factor_2 ratio plot]

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to do this. I can get it to work, so this is progress.

The main missing part is having a secondary y axis for the "ratio" item, which is quite important. I usually manually rescale the axes (if I'm working in Excel, for example), so that the columns of the "denominator" series are a lot smaller (ie underneath) the line of the "ratio" series - this is a convenient way to reduce the risk of being confused between the two.

I may well be able to work this out for myself...

Comment: Actually, no I can't :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame("Factor_1" = c(1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2),
             "Factor_2" = c("M", "F", "M", "F","M", "F","M", "F","M", "F","M", "F"),
             "Denominator" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
             "Numerator" = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1))




df %>% group_by(Factor_1) %>% summarize(sum_num=sum(Numerator),sum_dem=sum(Denominator)) %>% mutate(ratio=sum_num/sum_dem)

A tibble: 2 x 4
Factor_1 sum_num sum_dem ratio
   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
       1       3       7 0.429
       2       1       5 0.2
```

Does this help?